# What type of theft does Lo Signov refer to?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, gezel-stealing, parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, vaeschanan

One of the Aseres Hadevarim (more commonly referred to as "Dibros") is "לא תגנוב".  I can think of different types of theft / Geneivah such as stealing money/possesions, Geneivas Daas, and kidnapping. Is there a particular type of Geneivah/theft that is specifically referred to here, or is it referring to any type of theft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.13?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.20.13.2&lang2=bi) and [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.13?lang=bi&p2=Ramban_on_Exodus.20.13.1&lang2=bi) hold (citing Rabbi Yoshiyah in [Sanhedrin 86a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.86a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that "lo tignov" in [Shemot 20:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.13?lang=bi) means that one should not kidnap another person. Rashi's reasoning is that those who break the commandments of "lo tirtzah" and "lo tin'af" are subject to the death penalty, so it makes sense that one who breaks  "lo tignov" also is subject to the death penalty. And since you aren't held to the death penalty for theft but you are for kidnapping, he concludes that "lo tignov" must refer to kidnapping and not theft. According to him, the general prohibition of theft is learned out of [Vayikra 19:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.11?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en).

[Sforno](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.13?lang=bi&p2=Sforno_on_Exodus.20.13.2&lang2=bi) agrees that the prohibition refers to kidnapping, but he also includes general theft in the prohibition as well. Interestingly, he includes the prohibition  of "stealing someone's mind", meaning making someone believe a lie is truth.

And of course, countless of other commentaries believe "lo tignov" refers to all kinds of stealing.

Comment: This example is used by Artscroll to illustrate דבר הלמד מענינו

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the Seporno mentioned by Ezra, there a few other rishonim who also include monetary theft in Lo Signov.

R. Saadia Gaon writes:

> לא תגנב לא תסרק

R. Avraham Ben Harambam writes:

> פשטיה דקרא אזהרה על כל גניבה שיש בכלל אזהרה זו גניבת הממון וזולתו
>   והקרקע וגניבת הנפשות ור' סעדיה ז"ל אמר שיש בכלל התראה זו גם גניבת ממון
>   העשיר ויפה אמר והמעתיקים ז"ל פירטו את האזהרה בגונב נפש מישראל שהוא מן
>   החמורות

Ibn Ezra writes:

> לא תגנוב משמע גנבה קחת ממון בסתר ויש גנב שהוא בן מות כמו גונב נפש
>   מישראל בין שהוא נער קטן או נלעג לשון והגנבה בממון בין בפניו בין שלא
>   בפניו או שרמהו בחשבון או במדה או במשקל וזאת המלה גם היא כוללת מי
>   שיגנוב לב אחר כאשר עשה אבשלום

Note that Shadal specifically mentions that Chazal interpret it as a prohibition against kidnapping, while the peshat includes monetary theft:

> לא תגנוב לקיחת ממון אחרים בלא ידיעתם ורז"ל עשוהו אזהרה לגונב נפשות
>   שמצאנו בו עונש בלא אזהרה פרטית ולפי הפשט הרי זו אזהרה לכל מיני גנבה
>   ולהלן פירש עונשם כל מין בפני עצמו

R. Dovid Tzvi Hoffman asserts that despite the fact that Chazal interpreted Lo Signov as kidnapping and Lo Signovu as monetary theft, we see from other sources that they also included monetary theft in Lo Signov.

> ואמנם ראינו שחכמינו רואים בפסוקנו גם איסור גניבת ממון שהרי רבן יוחנן
>   בן זכאי אומרה כמין חומר אוזן ששמעה לא תגנב והלך וגנב היא תירצע מכל
>   אבריו ובדומה לזה מונח בארון זה (יוסף) קיים מה שכתוב במונח בארון זה
>   (הלוחות) לא תגנב לא גנב משל פרעה שנאמר וילקט יוסף את כל הכסף ועוד ראיה
>   במכילתא מובא כיצד ניתנו עשרת הדברות ה' על לוח זה וה' על לוח זה כתוב לא
>   תשא את שם ה' אלהיך לשוא וכנגדו כתוב לא תגנב מגיד הכתוב שכל מי שהוא
>   גונב לסוף בא לידי שבועת שוא שנאמר הגנוב רצוח ונאוף והישבע לשקר וכתוב
>   אלה וכחש ורצח וגנב ונאף והרי הקבלה זו אין לה מקום אלא אם כן נאמר כי
>   (גם) בגניבת ממון מדובר כאן

There is an interesting story about this question recorded by [R. Yechezkel Feivel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechezkel_Feivel) in *Toldos Adam* Chapter 4, about R. Shlomo Zalman of Vilna:

> סיפר לי איש מופלא בתורה
>
> פעם אחת אמר איש לרעהו דרך צחוק הסידור תפלה שלי שהנחתי פה איננו אולי ר'
>   זלמן גנב ועבר על לא תגנוב ויען ר' זלמן לו יהיה שגנבתי חלילה הסידור שלך
>   לא עברתי על לא תגנוב וכל יודעי ספר אשר היו שמה בעת ההיא עמדו כמשתאים
>   ומתפלאים על זה ויאמרו הלא תלמוד ערוך הוא לא תגנוב אפילו על מנת להחזיר
>   לא תגנוב אפילו על מנת למיקט
>
> ענה הצדיק הס מלהזכיר זה לא תגנבו האמור הוא אזהרה לגונב ממון אפילו על
>   מנס למיקט או לצער אבל לא תגנב האמור בעשרת הדברות הוא אזהרה לגונב נפשות
>
> A man distinguished in Torah told me:
>
> One time a man jokingly said to his friend, "my prayerbook that I left
>   here is not here; perhaps R. Zalman stole it and violated 'Lo
>   Signov'". R. Zalman replied, "even had I, Heaven forbid, stolen your
>   prayerbook I would not have violated 'Lo Signov'". All the
>   knowledgeable people present at the time stood astounded and
>   flabbergasted at this. They said, "Is it not a laid out Talmud[ic
>   law]? 'Lo Signov – even with intent to return, Lo Signov – even with
>   intent to annoy'".
>
> The tzaddik replied, "silence from mentioning this! Lo Signovu which was said is
>   the warning against monetary theft, even with intent to annoy or cause
>   pain. But Lo Signov which was said in the 10 Utterances is the warning
>   against kidnapping."

Comment: I'm surprised that those around R' Zalman had not read Rashi on "Lo Tignov". See my answer above.

Comment: Also surprising that this person would so offended by Seforno's position that he would attempt to eradicate it

Comment: @DoubleAA Perhaps he was trying to distinguish between peshat and halacha.

Comment: @Alex how on earth did you notice that tiny typo to edit it now?  Did you come back to read your answer?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I always throw in a few typos into my answers so that I can fix them at a later date and knock it back to the top of the list.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Just kidding. I often reread my answers and I spotted the typo while doing so.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות You didn't notice this one at the same time? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/90001/revisions

Comment: @Alex wow.  Maybe I should follow that lead and start rereading mine over again.  Although I will admit that I originally thought that it was purposeful.

Comment: @Alex although there are more typos in that sentence that you should fix.

Comment: @Alex מנס should be מנת

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Good catch. Fixed.