# Punishment for breaking the 10 commandments

Tags: aseres-hadibros

I would like to find the Mishna juridicial decision of the 10 Commandments (Exodus 20:2-13, Deuteronomy 5:6-17) which states the punishments for breaking said commandments in summary form.

Comment: "in summary form": you assume that the Mishna summarizes all the ten in one place. That's quite an assumption.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya, Cat. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/14850) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I do not think such a mishna exists. Maybe you can rephrase your question and ask what is the punishment for violating each of the 10 commandments. Adding some motivation for why you want to know would also be helpful - if it is beyond mere intellectual curiosity. Welcome again!

Answer (score 7):

The Mishna arranges laws topically, and so the ten commandments aren't discussed together.

1. I am the Lord your God: No punishment is discussed regarding this verse to my knowledge
2. Idol worship: Stoning (Sanhedrin 7:4)
3. Swearing in vain: Lashes (Shevuot 3:8)
4. Desecration of Sabbath: Stoning (Sanhedrin 7:4).
5. Honoring parents: No punishment is discussed to my knowledge
6. Murder: Decapitation (Sanhedrin 9:1)
7. Adultery: Choking (Sanhedrin 11:1, numbered chapter 10 in Gemara)
8. Kidnapping: Choking (Sanhedrin 11:1, numbered chapter 10 in Gemara)
9. Bearing false witness: Lashes (Makkot 1:3)
10. Coveting: No punishment is discussed to my knowledge

However, a short list can't give a full picture. Some punishments are disputed or only apply in specific circumstances. The eighth commandment, for instance, is [interpreted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89053/1569) in multiple ways so as to include either/both theft and kidnapping, and the punishment, of course, depends on the interpretation. The punishment for striking a parent (Exodus 21:15) is given as choking (Sanhedrin 11:1), and yet it isn't specifically connected to the honoring of parents in the ten commandments. In addition, many of these are listed more than once in the Mishna, so that idolatry, desecrating the Sabbath and adultery are also listed (Keretot 1:1) with those punished with [karet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44578/1569), even though they are already mentioned in the list above.

Comment: This is remarkable - how did you do this? You knew it or looked for it?

Comment: @mbloch I knew the lists in Sanhedrin, which are 5/10 commandments (also checked Makkot 3 and Keretot 1 but didn't use them), and looked for the others by looking at the tractates that discuss them and doing text searches to double check the others

Comment: This is what “having your learning in your hand” means”! Kol hakavod.

Comment: _Eidim zomemim_ are executed if their conspiracy leads to an execution http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0519.htm#19

Comment: Perhaps worth noting in the answer that only Deuteronomy has desecration of the sabbath.